# Can not see the first element of "getElementsByClassName"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure in my html:

```
<div class="miejsce">
<div class="blok3">
1
</div>
<div class="blok3" id="x">
2
</div>
<div class="blok3">
3
</div>
<div class="blok3">
4
</div>
</div>

<div class="miejsce">
<div class="blok3">
1
</div>
<div class="blok3">
2
</div>
<div class="blok3">
3
</div>
<div class="blok3" id="x">
4.
</div>
</div>
```

And I want to add parameter display: block to first elemets of divs with class "miejsce". I used for this getElementsByClassName and 'for' loop. See my JS:

```
var miejsca = document.getElementsByClassName('miejsce');

for(var i=0; i<miejsca.length; i++)
{
    alert("work2");
    miejsca[i].first().css('display', 'block');
}
```

Alert "work" was shown only once so problem is probably with:

```
miejsca[i].first().css('display', 'block');
```

Do you see any mistakes in my code? Please explain.

Comment: Please use english in ur code! It is easier to understand and recognise then

Comment: OK, sory but you can see just this same letters like "8uhf8f0" in html and "8uhf8f0" in js and connect it. I will use english next time.

Comment: It would be better for future visitors, if you did the translation even for this post. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery functions are not directly available on DOM elements. You need to wrap them in a jQuery object.

You can simplify all your code to this

```
$('.miejsce div:first-child').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: But how it works when I have 2 "miejsce" divs? I changed this line and code still do not work. Now alert "work" is shown 2 times.

Comment: Updated the question with new code, I misunderstood your question. You should probably look more into jQuery to use it at its full potential.